# Passing variables to runspaces and back

Tags: powershell

so I have the following code:

```
#region Initialize stuff
$files = gci "C:\logs\*.log"
$result = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::Synchronized((New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList))

$RunspaceCollection = @()
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,5)
$RunspacePool.Open()

$ScriptBlock = {
    Param($file, $result)
    $content = Get-Content $file.FullName -ReadCount 0
    foreach ($line in $content) {
        if ($line -match 'A002') {
        [void]$result.Add($($line -replace ' +',","))
}}}
#endregion

#region Process Data
Foreach ($file in $files) {
    $Powershell = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock).AddArgument($file).AddArgument($result)
    $Powershell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    [Collections.Arraylist]$RunspaceCollection += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        Runspace = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()
        PowerShell = $PowerShell  
}}

While($RunspaceCollection) {
    Foreach ($Runspace in $RunspaceCollection.ToArray()) {
        If ($Runspace.Runspace.IsCompleted) {
            [void]$result.Add($Runspace.PowerShell.EndInvoke($Runspace.Runspace))
            $Runspace.PowerShell.Dispose()
            $RunspaceCollection.Remove($Runspace)
}}}
#endregion

#region Parse Data
$data = ConvertFrom-Csv -InputObject $result -Header "1","2","3","TimeIn","TimeOut","4","5","Dur"
foreach ($line in $data) {
    if ($line.TimeIn -match "A002") { $TimeIn += [timespan]::Parse($line.Dur) }
    else { $TimeOut += [timespan]::Parse($line.Dur) }}
#endregion
```

It works, but I don't completely understand how ;)
what is `[System.Collections.ArrayList]::Synchronized((New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList))` and why does it work, while regular ArrayList doesn't? Why do I need this "Synchronized" and what it does? Could you please explain or point me to some materials about this? I can't seem to find anything relevant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To guarantee the thread safety of the ArrayList, all operations must
> be done through this wrapper.
>
> Enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe
> procedure. Even when a collection is synchronized, other threads can
> still modify the collection, which causes the enumerator to throw an
> exception. To guarantee thread safety during enumeration, you can
> either lock the collection during the entire enumeration or catch the
> exceptions resulting from changes made by other threads.

## Source:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3azh197k(v=vs.110).aspx

This was found by googling

> ArrayList Synchronized Method

It would be most beneficial for you to learn the fundamentals of object oriented script/programming so in the future you know exactly what to look for. There are many ways to implement .NET namespaces, classes, methods, and elements in a powershell host, `[System.Collections.ArrayList]::Synchronized((New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList))` being one of them.